# Targeting elements in jquery - No slide up/down

Tags: jquery

New to jquery. The desire is to show/hide horizontal menu bar items. I have tried several iterations without success.

The CSS is working and styled, and javascript that sets the`li` and `a` tags class to "active" in the onload event. What am I missing? I am concluding the error is in the jquery, although it can't be much simpler. Explanations helpful. I would appreciate suggestions that use the existing html.

The main purpose of the div id=menu is to enable centering the bar.

My Script

**Edit 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li').hover(function() {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);
    }, function() {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
    });
});​
```

My Html

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li id="lhome" class="">
            <a href="index.php" id="ahome" class="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="lprod" class="">
            <a href="products.php" id="aprod" class="">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="ltest" class="">
            <a href="testimonial.php" id="atest" class="">Testimonials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="lcont" class="">
            <a href="contact.php" id="acont" class="">Contact&nbsp;Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks alright to me. Any console errors? Can you set up a JS Fiddle to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Can you post all of your HTML? Are you sure that you're loading the jQuery library?

Comment: @Utkanos No console errors. I don't use JS Fiddle (yet). Will plug in CSS into Francois's demo below to see

Comment: See the DEMO link below for CSS code and non-working jquery. Thanks to all commenters.

Comment: @François Wahl has a working demo with jQuery. jsfiddle.net/urhDr/8 What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Take the jQuery out of the LL panel and what changes? To my eyes, nothing. It seems the CSS is overriding the jQuery. The **slideDown/slideUp** do not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code seems to be working fine, see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urhDr/)

**Edit**

Based on your feedback I done some more research and I found that your CSS is interfering with the animation.

If you look at the original demo I linked above which has no styles you see the slide down/up takes the 100 milliseconds as specified.

If you look at your [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urhDr/8/) with the CSS you see the menus just appear.

After a little trial and error I pinpointed the CSS causing this.
If you remove the below section from the CSS your animation of the sub-menu is working again as expected.

```
/* Make the sub menus appear on hover */
#menu ul li:hover ul,
#menu ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   display:block; /* Show the sub menus */
}
```

The above CSS overwrites the animation from the slide down/up methods and simply displays the sub-menu as a block instead. It still works if you leave the IE6 fix in but you have to remove the CSS for `#menu ul li:hover ul` :

```
/* Make the sub menus appear on hover */
#menu ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
   display:block; /* Show the sub menus */
}
```

I applied the changes to the fiddle and it is working now.
See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/urhDr/14/)

Comment: Thanks for help Francois. I plugged in my CSS and it is acting the same as I've experienced. Is there a way to save the CSS to that demo?

Comment: I think I discovered 'Update'. Can you see it there?

Comment: @DavidC: When you click update the url is updated, you can post that then. I think I found it though: http://jsfiddle.net/urhDr/8/ The fiddle looks fine though. I'm using it in Chrome. The menus are opening up on hover. Is that not what you would expect?

Comment: The addition of jquery code changes nothing. After setting the time to 1000, still nothing changes.

Comment: @DavidC: I'm not sure I understand the issue. In the demo, when you hover over `Products` or `Testimonials` the additional menu pops out. When you say `nothing changes`, does the sub-menu not show for you? or do you expect anything else to happen after it popped up?

Comment: Aha. I saw the menu items 'just appearing'. i.e. NO SLIDE. Now, finally, I'm beginning to see the slide. So why are they not 'sliding' in/out with the original example?

Comment: In your demo, go back to the original `$('ul', this).slideDown(100);` and see if the items 'slide' down or just appear? Many thanks for your persistence. I may have asked the question incorrectly.

Comment: @DavidC: I found eventually out why. It is your CSS. In your CSS you specify to show the sub-menu as block when hovered over. This overwrites the animation and simply displays the `ul` as block.