# Need jquery syntax to make slideToggle disappear when another item is touched - Mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

**Edit 1**
This is about **touch events**. The intent is to have action (on mobile devices) with one touch -> extend, 2nd touch retract. Touch another item -> it extends & previous retracts.

Here's the rub: iPad 4.3.3 works great. iPhone 5.1 & 6.0, & Android 4 - 2nd touch retracts and extends. Not the desired effect. Check out an [example here](https://flydata.mobi/bella/) Thanks for looking.

Is this a bug in jQuery or the mobile OS's ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android/i))) {
        $('#nav li').click(function(){
            // attach a click event listener to provoke iPhone/iPod/iPad's hover event
            // Amended the next 3 lines 
            var $this_li = $(this);  
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp(function() {
                $('ul', $this_li).slideDown();
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#nav li').hover(
            function () {
                //show its submenu
                $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
            }, 
            function () {
                //hide its submenu
                $('ul', this).slideUp(200);         
            }
        ); 
    }  
});
```

Comment: [HTML code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820372/targeting-elements-in-jquery-no-slide-up-down) <-- Link

Comment: @David Lesches Thanks for edit 2. To any interested, please see edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First retract **all** the li's, then slidedown the clicked one in the slideup's callback. this way the clicked li slides down after the current li has been retracted.

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){  
    var $this_li = $(this);  
    $('#nav li ul').slideUp(function() {
        $('ul', $this_li).slideDown();
    });
});
} else {
```

etc

Comment: Wow. That made all the menu items slide up and disappear. :(  Got another idea?

Comment: @DavidC I've revised the code slightly should work better for u now

Comment: Only one down at a time. The revision causes them all to slide up, disappear and for the selected on to reappear by itself. The other 3 are gone.  :(

Comment: Oh boy, misunderstood that you had sub-ul's. ok i made an additional two edits, should work now. is the code online somewhere so I can have a look?

Comment: That last edit did the trick perfectly. Can you give a short explanation of your lines 2-4? Thanks

Comment: Ah, finally :) OK so first we save $(this), the clicked li, to a variable. we do this b/c the context of $(this) can change later and we don't want issues. Then we tell jquery to find every ul which is a child of an li (or in english, every SUBmenu), slide them up. Then we add a function to that - this is called a callback, it gets triggered AFTER the previous function finishes. So after all the submenus slide up - you only actually see one slide up, cause one is down, but all have been triggered to slide up - you then tell jquery to find the ul which is a child of our $this_li

Comment: our $this_li variable - ie our clicked li - and slide down just that submenu. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your 2nd solution turned up not working correctly on iPhone and Android. If you have another idea, please see Edit 1 to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var test = 0;
$('#nav li').click(function(){
    if(test == 0) {
        $('ul', this).slideDown();
        test = 1;
    } else {
        $('ul', this).slideUp();
        test = 0;
    }
});
```

this is the on/off switch you were talking about that you could test

Comment: Great idea. That's not working either. Select an item, the sub-menu slides down. Select another, and neither moves.  :(

Comment: @DavidC could you share you HTML code so i can see what your elements look like? thanks :)